# webpack issue when trying to render in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, webpack

Hi I am a newbie in react js and was trying to build an quiz application..When trying to do so I am getting an error when the render is getting called..

The below is the webpack.config file:-

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },

  // Add resolve.extensions.
  // '' is needed to allow imports without an extension.
  // Note the .'s before extensions as it will fail to match without!!!
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6.js']
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'app/js/main.js'
  },
  module: {
    loader: [
//      {
//        test: /\.css$/,
//        loaders: ['style', 'css'],
//       // include: PATHS.app
//
//      },
      // Set up jsx. This accepts js too thanks to RegExp
     {
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
 presets:['es2015','react'],
  loader: 'jsx-loader'
//  query: {
//    presets: ['react']
//        }
     }
    ]
  }
};
```

The following is my index.js file:-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);

//React.createElement(People, {})
```

the following is my App.jsx:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div>Appppppoihj</div>
        )
    }

}

export default App
```

The most interesting part is that I am getting an error in my index.js file while I am trying to call `renderDOM.render`..

The issue I am getting is :-

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Th\Desktop\ReactJs_Master\src\index.js Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:4)
```

The following is my package.json:-

```
{
  "name": "react_quiz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "quiz with the help of reactjs",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Pratham",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies":{
      "babel-core":"5.8.*",
      "babel-loader":"5.3.*",
      "webpack":"1.12.*"
  },
  "dependencies":{
      "react":"15.0.1",
      "react-dom":"15.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried out all different websites and solutions on this website but none of them is helping me so far..The error is coming at `<` in the app component when calling `reactDOM.render`

I would of much help if any of you all could help me out as I am stuck for a long time on this and not getting any sort of solution for this..

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: one of the reasons I was getting this is because of the npm modules I had installed before hand..As @alexander pointed out I removed the npm module and used the commands and the code changes he has recommended below..It worked out for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `jsx-loader` try use [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
    }]
  }
```

**Note** - *Make sure that you have installed these packages*

```
npm i babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

- [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)
- [babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core)
- [babel-preset-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015)
- [babel-preset-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react)

**Update**

also you can move `presets` option from `webpack.config` to `.babelrc`

```
{ 
   "presets": ["es2015", "react"] 
}
```